# No save when forwarding an action?

Tags: grails, action, grails-orm, forward

Grails 2.2.0

I'm exploring grails and ajax, and maybe I'm an overzealous ajax adaptor, but I really think its a gamechanger, so I'm going in headfirst.

Datamodel is a master detail (1:n). A table in the client shows a piece of the list of master's properties. And upon clicking, the line folds open showing all the details (An attribute domain) and an option to add a new detail to the unfolded master. All well, opening this line calls

```
def show (Long id) {
    def product = Product.get(id)
    log.info('show ' + (request.xhr ? 'xerhr' : 'normal') + "product is ${product.title}")
    def c = Attribute.createCriteria();
    def attributeTypes = LookupValue.findByType('m_attr') //list of values for dropdown menu.
    def result = c {
        eq("movie", product)
    }
    for (attr in result) {
        log.info('value: ${attr.value}')
    }
    render ([template: "attributes", model:[focus:params.id
        , attributeList: result, attributeTypes: attributeTypes]])
}
```

Where the attributes templates displays all the related attributes (details) and an add option at the end where you can enter a new value and select a value from a dropdown menu. The client does do an ajax post back to the controller's saveAttribute method to save this new Attribute:

```
def saveAttribute(Long id, Long luv_id, String value) {
    def attribute = new Attribute(movie : Product.get(id)
        , label : LookupValue.get(luv_id)
        , value : value);
    attribute.save();
    show();
}
```

and again calls `show()` to render the newly created list of attributes back to the client. Now show() does render all the existing attributes but it fails to retrieve the just created attribute whereas it definitely did end up in the database. It also shows up when I reload the page. Where do I go wrong? With hibernate I think I would do a `session.flush()` to get over this.

And maybe my architecture is wrong and I need to define a service and introducing some transaction boundaries?

Comment: That is not how you forward.  `forward(action: "show", id: id)`

Comment: Also, get rid of your semi-colons!

Comment: Also, Ajax was a game changer 5 years ago.

Comment: @James the forward also does not force the flush/commit

Comment: @Gregg, Well I have been under a jsf/j2ee/websphere rock for a few years, maybe I'd better jump the socketio wagon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def saveAttribute(Long id, Long luv_id, String value) {
    Attribute attribute = new Attribute(movie: Product.get(id)
        , label: LookupValue.get(luv_id)
        , value: value).save(flush: true)
    forward(action: "show", id: id)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, flush: true does it. what does forward do extra above the direct show()- method call? In my particular case I don't see any difference?

Comment: To tell you the truth I really don't know, however I know the convention is to always forward, return, or redirect from an action